# can we use two nested routes in react router dom v6 with colon symbol( : )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I create a react website [My website](https://fastnews77.netlify.app/)

**Please check my website for more understanding**

https://fastnews77.netlify.app/

On the blog page, I added two nested routes

```
 <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} >
        <Route path="" element={<Allblogs />} />
        <Route path=":id" element={<Post />} />
        <Route path=':tagVal' element = {<TagPost /> } />
  </Route>
```

The first Blog component render

```
Blog title
```

the second Allblogs component render

```
All blogs
```

then I used 2 nested routes

1. Post component for individual post
2. TagPost components for tag related all blogs

**But when I click any tag it will render the Post component of any random blog**

what i add in tagPost component

```
const { tagVal } = useParams();
```

**check this link for code**

[Github Code Link][2]

**Please suggest some code or reference for this problem**

[2]:

Comment: How would it know it is different? Answer, it can't so you need to make the paths different somehow.

Comment: Your question and needed info needs to be here, not in your website. If you direct people there, your question will be pointless once your website changes -- aka when you get your issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can nest routes with dynamic path parameters, but you can't specify two route paths with the same specificity. `react-router@6` uses a [Route Ranking](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#ranking-routes) system. The path pattern's rank for the `Post` component is equal to that of the `TagPost` route path and will mask it. You'll need to differentiate/disambiguate the sub-routes, for example placing the `TagPost` component an another sub-route like `"/blog/tag/:tagVal"`.

Example:

```
<Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} >
  <Route index element={<Allblogs />} />
  <Route path=":id" element={<Post />} />
  <Route path='/tag/:tagVal' element={<TagPost />} />
</Route>
```